# In reverse bias p-n junction diode, how do one know that the kinetic energy of the tunnelling electron is lower than the energy of the barrier?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-tunneling

In reverse bias p-n junction diode, how do one know that the kinetic energy of the (thermally generated in the p-side) tunnelling electron is actually lower than the energy of the barrier (the depletion region)?

Comment: if it were not lower, it would not be tunneling. By definition of tunneling the energy of the particle is lower than the barrier energy.  see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, nobody has a model for the observed negative resistance of a tunnel diode that *doesn't* involve tunneling. So, ultimately, it's the behavior of the physical device that demands it. That's physics.

Comment: in a tunnel diode the negative resistance happens in *forward* bias

Answer (score 0):

From this reference: https://ecstudiosystems.com/discover/textbooks/basic-electronics/diodes/tunnel-diodes/

> [image]

This image contains all the proof. If you compare the IV curve of a normal pn junction (dashed line) you will see that between Points 1 through 2, electrons have passed through a narrow depletion region without loss of energy and at potentials lower than the barrier height. Also barrier width is as important (if not more so) as barrier height. In the Esaki diode tunneling occurs through a barrier width that is extremely thin at zero bias. An applied potential can also change this width.

The paper I have referenced is a nice overview.

Comment: The image does not contain any proof. It merely assumes that "this is the case".

Comment: The graphs in the image are representative of actual device behavior. If you purchase a pn diode or tunnel diode and perform IV measurements they will look nearly identical to the curves in the image. So the image is based on real device performance

Comment: So what? As it was already pointed out, the real performance is just that: real device performance. I don't have idea how can that be a proof for the kinetic energy of the tunnelling electron being lower than the energy of the barrier.